# Flutter build error 'xcode_backend.dart' switch case may fall thorough to the next case

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart

I am trying to run my flutter app on my MacBook Pro (intel), but I always get this error.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            7,6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2023-09-04 16:05:42.136 xcodebuild[19368:139168] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via
    user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/q2/qyvl4rr11cs5w94s5lchqnm80000gn/T/flutter_tools.ScnHIY/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirJfc1zY/temporary_xcresu
        lt_bundle

    /Library/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:50:7: Error: Switch case may fall through to
    the next case.
          case 'build':
          ^
    /Library/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:55:7: Error: Switch case may fall through to
    the next case.
          case 'embed':
          ^
    /Library/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.dart:57:7: Error: Switch case may fall through to
    the next case.
          case 'embed_and_thin':
          ^
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/jorge/repos/FlutterApp/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.4.99.
    (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/jorge/repos/FlutterApp/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target
    'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.4.99.
    (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
    note: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase
    "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    note: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because the option to run the script phase
    "Based on dependency analysis" is unchecked. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/q2/qyvl4rr11cs5w94s5lchqnm80000gn/T/flutter_tools.ScnHIY/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirJfc1zY/temporary_xcresu
        lt_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.2, on macOS 13.5.1 22G90 darwin-x64, locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 3.13.2 on channel stable at /Library/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ff5b5b5fa6 (11 days ago), 2023-08-24 08:12:28 -0500
    • Engine revision b20183e040
    • Dart version 3.1.0
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jorge/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14E300c
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.72.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 14 Pro (mobile) • CF27AB84-1030-4E3C-AFA2-C93A072A7B9F • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)        • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 13.5.1 22G90 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 116.0.5845.140

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

I have tried all of this, but still the same error:

- Run 'flutter clean' and then 'flutter pub get'
- Run 'flutter pub cache repair'
- Delete 'Pods' folder, run 'pod install'
- Delete 'Podfile.lock', run 'flutter pub get'
- Delete 'ios' folder (saving 'Runner'), then run 'flutter create .' and restore 'Runner' folder.
- And some more things I don't remember xd.

Thanks in advance!!